# Twisted class versions runs well with old java VM, not on new java VM. It's regular?

Tags: java, class, version

It would seem that a class hierarchy with mixed older (very old) a newer classes runs well in java VM 1.4.2, not in newer VM. I'd like to know if anyone has run into the same issue.

I'm working with an old project, there is a compiled class with a hierarchy made in this way:

Base class (Foo1), compiled with java 1.4
Intermiediate class (Foo2) that extends Foo1, compiled with java 1.1
Intermediate class (Foo3) that extends Foo2, compiled with hava 1.4
My class (Bar) that extends Foo3, in my src folder, that is to compile and to execute.

If I run my project with Java 1.4, it runs well.
If I run my project with Java 1.6 or newer, it return an invalid signature for some methods in the class Foo2.

In particular:
The following row:

```java
Bar bar = Bar.getBarFromId(currentId);
```

retrieve the exception

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Foo2, method: setIdAzienda signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
```

If I clean and build my project, I have the following exception at the same location:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Foo2, method: setAziendaKey signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
```

The third time the error is in another method:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Foo2, method: setOrdinamFaldone signature: (C)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
```

The method I call (getBarFromId) is the following one:

```java
public static Foo3 getBarFromId(String  id) {
    if (id == null)
        return null;
    try {
        return (Foo3) Foo1.readElementWithKey(Foo3.class, id);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the stack trace of the exception doens't mentioned any row inside this routine.

NB: Foo1, Foo2 and Foo3 are stored into a jar I'm not the owner. The jar is very big and I don't know if it is the only case where I have that kind of issue or there are a lot of classes to recompile (I haven't sources and sometimes decompilers cannot to extract all methods)

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: The error I have is the following:** 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: «className, Foo2 in my example», method: «a random method (it's a different one every time I compile my source)» signature: (C)V) Incompatible object argument for function call **
Obiouvsly, the method is right signed, the stack trace doens't refer to that method (it's referrend to the initialization of the Foo4 class) and it doesn't retrieve the exception if I use VM 1.4

Comment: A different, random method every time you compile your source? Really? And what is Foo4 class? You only mentioned Foo1 Foo2 Foo3 and Bar above. I think you will have to show a minimal reproduceable example for people to help you with that. Or re-think if you really need to support this kind of cross-compilation using ancient Java versions. Why not recompile everything using a current Java version?

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned Foo4 class, but this is the Bar one. I show some examples of errors retrieved by different launches. Note: if I don't clean and build the project, the method that retrieve the error is always the same. Some times I received the exceptino also in methods without arguments. The exceptions referres to public method often not mentioned elsewhere inside the same class and they are well defined. Infact if I run it into JVM 1.4 I have no exceptions.

Comment: Hmm. So you have a jar file with classes that Java6+ refuses to load with verification errors. The most likely explanation is that the classes are broken/invalid, but that Java 1.4 did not detect this. You will have to get them fixed (recompiled, most likely) or stick with Java 1.4.